# How can I change page title when I use full page components-Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewires

```
<head>
   <title>dynamic title here - {{ config('app.name') }}</title>
</head>
```

if you try this, please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried with `->section` method like this`->section('body', ['title' => 'something'])` but it not work

Comment: Try putting the title on the `layout()` instead of the `section()`

Answer (score -1):

I preferred using JavaScript with Blade Components `document.title = 'My Title'`

Implemented with [Alpine JS](https://alpinejs.dev/)

**Blade Component (.../components/page-title.blade.php)**

```
@props(['title'])

<div x-data x-init="document.title = @js($title.' - '.config('app.name'))"></div>
```

so you can call the `page-title` component anywhere in your blade flies like this

```
<x-page-title :title="'Homepage'" />
```

There could be easier methods of doing it the JavaScript way, but this is what I could think of. Hope it helps

The **PHP** way could be to pass the `$title` as a prop to the layout, For Example

```
<x-guest-layout>
    <x-slot name="title">
       Custom Title
    </x-slot>

    ...Page Content
</x-guest-layout>
```

`guest-layout.blade.php` now looks like

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ $title ?? 'Todo Manager' }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <hr/>
    {{ $slot }}
</body>
```